# Unsupported keystore provider Type AZURE_KEY_STORE in SSMS creating Column Encryption Key

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms, always-encrypted

So after creating my Master Key using the Azure Key Store:

```
CREATE COLUMN MASTER KEY XXXX_CMK   
WITH (  
    KEY_STORE_PROVIDER_NAME = 'AZURE_KEY_STORE',  
    KEY_PATH = 'https://MyKeyVaultName.vault.azure.net/'        
)
```

I need to create the Column Encryption Key.
Since the CREATE COLUMN ENCRYPTION KEY syntax requires an ENCRYPTED_VALUE param that I don't have yet, I'm trying to create it in SSMS (v 18.6), but I'm getting an strange error:

[image: SSMS Error when adding Column Encryption Key]

The error is "Unsupported keystore provider Type AZURE_KEY_STORE"

How do I rectify this?
NB The db is in Azure, @@version returning

```
Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Sep 11 2020 22:32:15   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
```

Comment: Interestingly, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-column-master-key-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) even appears to be confused on the correct name, as it refers to it at first as `AZURE_KEY_VAULT` and later as `AZURE_KEY_STORE`, and then `AZURE_KEY_VAULT` again in the example. Does `AZURE_KEY_VAULT` work?

Comment: @Larnu - unfortunately not. I can recreate the Column Master key using "KEY_STORE_PROVIDER_NAME = 'AZURE_KEY_VAULT' " but I get a different error when trying to create the CEK : Invalid ObjectIdentifier [vault name].  Bad number of segments: 1 (Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault)

Answer (score 0):

This the script to create the COLUMN MASTER KEY:

```
CREATE COLUMN MASTER KEY [CMK_Auto1]
WITH
(
KEY_STORE_PROVIDER_NAME = N'AZURE_KEY_VAULT',
KEY_PATH = N'https://<your_vault>.vault.azure.net:443/keys/CMKAuto1/<key_identifier>'
)
GO
```

Please ref the Microsoft tutorial: [Using the Azure Key Vault Key Store Provider for Always Encrypted](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql/using-the-azure-key-vault-key-store-provider-for-always/ba-p/386089)